# Is there a way to resize the cells of only some specific cells that have an image with vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro running on an Excel file

```vb
Sub obtenerValores()
    ' Definir la tabla a iterar
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja2").ListObjects("TableTest")

    ' Definir la nueva hoja para almacenar los valores
    Dim nuevaHoja As Worksheet
    Set nuevaHoja = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    ' Definir la primera fila de la nueva hoja para escribir los valores
    Dim fila As Long
    fila = 1
    
    ' Iterar sobre las filas de la tabla
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
        ' Obtener los valores de las celdas de la fila actual
        Dim valor1 As Variant
        valor1 = tbl.DataBodyRange(i, 1).Value
        
        Dim valor2 As Variant
        valor2 = tbl.DataBodyRange(i, 2).Value
        
        Dim valor23 As Variant
        valor3 = tbl.DataBodyRange(i, 3).Value
        
        Dim valor4 As Variant
        valor4 = tbl.DataBodyRange(i, 5).Value
        
        Dim imageURL As Variant
        imageURL = "P:\00_PlanesyProgramas\JavierEstrada\2023\01_PDU_EstructuraVial\PropuestaAnexo\Secciones PNG\" & valor3 & ".png"
        
        ' Escribir los valores en la nueva hoja
        nuevaHoja.Cells.RowHeight = 30
        nuevaHoja.Cells.ColumnWidth = 100

        nuevaHoja.Cells(fila, 1).Value = valor1
        nuevaHoja.Cells(fila, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        fila = fila + 1

        nuevaHoja.Cells(fila, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        
        nuevaHoja.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=imageURL, _
            LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
            Left:=nuevaHoja.Cells(fila, 1).Left, Top:=nuevaHoja.Cells(fila, 1).Top, Width:=180, Height:=100
        fila = fila + 1
        

        nuevaHoja.Cells(fila, 1).Value = valor2
        nuevaHoja.Cells(fila, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        fila = fila + 1
        
        nuevaHoja.Cells(fila, 1).Value = valor4
        nuevaHoja.Cells(fila, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        fila = fila + 2
        
        nuevaHoja.Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 70
    Next i
End Sub
```

This iterates through the following table, retrieving only some values of the table located on another sheet
[image: Excel table]

This... kinda works, but my problem is that the image is floating over multiple cells:
[image: Image over multiple cells instead of just one]

But I want to make something like this:
[image: Correct image position]

How can I do it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (re-written a little...)

```vb
Sub obtenerValores()
    
    Dim tbl As ListObject, i As Long
    Dim nuevaHoja As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, shp As Shape
    Dim rng As Range, imageURL As String
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set tbl = wb.Worksheets("Hoja2").ListObjects("TableTest")
    Set nuevaHoja = wb.Worksheets.Add()
    
    With nuevaHoja
        .Cells.RowHeight = 30    'only need to do this once...
        .Cells.ColumnWidth = 100
        .Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 70
        .Columns(1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A4") 'location for the first row's data
    End With
    
    For i = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
        
        rng.Cells(1).Value = tbl.DataBodyRange(i, 1).Value
        rng.Cells(2).Value = tbl.DataBodyRange(i, 2).Value
        
        imageURL = "P:\00_PlanesyProgramas\JavierEstrada\2023\01_PDU_EstructuraVial\" & _
                   "PropuestaAnexo\Secciones PNG\" & tbl.DataBodyRange(i, 3).Value & ".png"
        
        'import and position the image...
        With rng.Cells(3)
            Set shp = nuevaHoja.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=imageURL, _
                        LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
                        Left:=.Left, Top:=.Top, Width:=180, Height:=100)
            .RowHeight = shp.Height 'set row height
        End With
        
        rng.Cells(4).Value = tbl.DataBodyRange(i, 5).Value
        
        Set rng = rng.Offset(6) 'next data range
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This one did it!
Thank you for your refactoring, I didn't realized how messy my code was.

Comment: I just needed to change a litte the line where you set the cell height, using the following:
nuevaHoja.Rows(rng.Row + 2).RowHeight = shp.Heigh

Comment: My bad  - changed `.Height` to `.RowHeight` above

Comment: FYI your code wasn't "messy" - just maybe a more verbose style than I'd typically use.  Fewer lines of code are easier to scan over.